# Multiple Column Count with Filter

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I tried searching for a solution, but couldn't get any formulae to fit my case.

In Power Pivot, I need separate counts of males and females who were selected and graduated in the respective columns, so it should be all F with Yes in column Selected as well for the case of selected females.

This is the Data on which I need to calculate the fields:
[image]

How can I do that?

Update: I need a solution though DAX, by creating a new field that can be used in pivots to make graphs.

Countifs function won't work here.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `=countifs` function in excel.

Comment: Nopes, countifs function doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

For men

```
=COUNTIFS(genderColumn;"=M";selectedColumn;"=yes")
```

For woman

```
=COUNTIFS(genderColumn;"=F";selectedColumn;"=yes")
```

Comment: No, I need solution through DAX. I am working on power pivots. Countifs fuctions doesn't seem to work here

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

It looks something like this for females:

`=COUNTIFS(E2:E999; "F"; J2:J999; "Yes"; K2:K999; "Yes")`

Answer (score 0):

For all selected and graduated:

```
Count = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table);Table[Selected]="Yes";Table[Graduated]="Yes")
```

Also filtered on Female:

```
Count = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table);Table[Selected]="Yes";Table[Graduated]="Yes";Table[Gender]="F")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

Might Help someone.

Male Applicants:=CALCULATE(COUNTA(Internship[GENDER]),FILTER(Internship,Internship[GENDER]="M" && Internship[APPLIED]="Yes"))

Female Applicants:=CALCULATE(COUNTA(Internship[GENDER]),FILTER(Internship,Internship[GENDER]="F" && Internship[APPLIED]="Yes"))

Same function for Selected and Graduate, just changed the table.

Thanks anyways